# Group products by family

Tags: apex, controller, custom-controller

Updated
I've updated the question because it was not clear and some of you gave me hints.What i originally want to achieve is the following example on visualforce page

I want them to be grouped and rendered as:

```
-Family
 -Brand
  -Product1
  -Product2
  -Product3
-Family
 -Brand
  -Product1
  -Product2
  -Product3
```

I am trying to create a visualforce page that will group products by Family/Brand.
Can anyone advise me how or what is the easiest way to do this? I am trying to render the page as PDF for my sales team.

**Controller**

```
    public with sharing class StandardProductDisplayController{ 
public List<Product2> records {get; set;} 
public StandardProductDisplayController(){ 
records = [select Name, ProductCode, Brand__c, Family from Product2 order by Family]; 
} 
}
```

**Apex**

```
   <apex:page controller="StandardProductDisplayController" renderAs="pdf"> 
    <apex:pageBlock title="Product List"> 
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!records}" var="record"> 
            <apex:column > 
                <apex:facet name="header">Product Name</apex:facet> 
                <apex:outputText value="{!record.Name}"/> 
            </apex:column> 
            <apex:column > 
                <apex:facet name="header">Product Brand</apex:facet> 
                <apex:outputText value="{!record.Brand__c}"/> 
            </apex:column> 
            <apex:column > 
                <apex:facet name="header">Family</apex:facet> 
                <apex:outputText value="{!record.Family}"/> 
            </apex:column> 
        </apex:pageBlockTable> 
    </apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: That SOQL query will not execute unless you change `GroupParameter` to `Brand__c`. Aggregate queries require that you summarize or group all `SELECT`ed fields.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

If you just want to order your `Product2` records by family, do not use aggregate queries. Instead, include an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT Name, Brand__c, Family__c FROM Product2 ORDER BY Family
```

**Original**

You cannot select individual fields on each record if you are performing an aggregate query. Each field must be *grouped* (e.g. `GROUP BY Family`) or *aggregated* (e.g. `count(Name)`).

If you just want to know how many records are in each family, it can be done:

```
SELECT Family, count(Id) FROM Product2 GROUP BY Family
```

Now the default alias for each aggregation is `expr0`, `expr1`, etc. Since you have just one here, you would use the zero index.

```
<apex:column value="{!aggregate['Family]} />
<apex:column value="{!aggregate['expr0']} />
```

Note, however, that aggregate queries support *aliasing* of these expressions to make your code/markup more readable.

```
SELECT Family, count(Id) recordCount ...
```

If you add such an alias, you can change your second column field name from `expr0` to `recordCount`.

Comment: Thanks Adrian for your fast reply, But i am not seeking to find the number of records. Maybe my query and approach is bad. I am seeking to list all products by family and show them on the page.

Comment: Hi Adrian,  I've updated the question for more clearance you gave me a good hint.